# How to enable office add-in (word) in SharePoint 2013 environment?

Tags: vsto, sharepoint-2013, office-addins

We have created add-in for MS-Word which enables us to apply some custom actions in the document. For that we need to install that add-in in our local system.

Now we have configured office web app to open the word doc in SharePoint 2013 environment. We want to enable that office add-in in the word doc when it opens in SharePoint 2013 environment in browser. So, how can achieve this?

If it is not possible, then we have to recreate add-in as office web app to run into SharePoint. So please provide information on how to create the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use addins developed for the desktop version of Office in Sharepoint environment. In fact developing for online versions is quite limited at this moment. You can find more information on how to develop for different environments on this Microsoft page: [Office developer documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn467914%28v=office.15%29.aspx)